# Regex to seperate request uri by 'real' page request and image/js/css requests

Tags: regex

I want to filter out all entries in my access logs that have a request uri which are requesting static recources like images, js, css, xml. The goal is to have an minfied access log wich only contains 'real' page request.

I'm trying to find a regex that fits my purpose and here's the point where  I would like to ask for your help.

Here are some examples:

Strings I want to match:

```
r:GET / HTTP/1.1
r:GET /m HTTP/1.1
r:GET /autor/William-Mills/Deep-Hunting-Shallow-Fishing-8163700-t/ HTTP/1.1 
r:GET /?wicket:interface=:1::IActivePageBehaviorListener:15:2&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true HTTP/1.1
```

Strings I **not** want to match: (One could say all that contains something like `.xxx` before the `?querystring` )

```
r:GET /js/global.js?v=17 HTTP/1.1
r:GET /js/global.js HTTP/1.1  
r:GET /img/icon_action_arrow.png HTTP/1.1
r:GET /img/icon_action_arrow.PNG HTTP/1.1
```

I endend up, having a regex like this:

```
"r:[A-Z]+ \\S*(?!(?i)\\.jpg|\\.png|\\.gif|\\.js|\\.css|\\.xml)(\\?| )"
```

(With a real whitespace at the end)

But this is matching exactly the opposite, maching everything I **not** want to match and not matching everything I want to have.

Thanks in advance for any hints, help or advices!

Comment: Have you tried to filter out what you dont want basing on the file extension?

Comment: do you want only regex to match the text you've shown above or it's going to be used for others that are like it?

Comment: The tesxt shown above are only some examples. Basically Alex's idea is good. But my regex skills are limited :( I have this one right now which I need to negate, because I dont want to match the image/css stuff and this regex is matching all of them: "r:[A-Z]+ \\S*(\\.jpg|\\.png|\\.gif|\\.js|\\.css|\\.xml)(\\?| )"

Comment: so you don't want with .jpg .png .gif .js .css .xml extensions only right?

Comment: yes thats right. the regex in my comment is matching all I don't want, and none of the ones I want. I just need to negate it, but I cant get it...

Comment: You probably don't need to do the 'negation' in the regex itself. Match the things you don't want, then if you're using grep use the `--invert-match` switch. If you're using vim, do a `g/pattern/d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
r:[A-Z]+\s([^\s\.]+)\s
```

It's a slight twist on yours, allowing a space before the path and then paths that do not contain full stops followed by another space. Really depends if you simply can just ignore paths with a full stop or you need to be more definitive.

**Edit :**

```
r:[A-Z]+\s((?:[^\s\.]+)|(?:[^\s\.]+\?.*))\s
```

Does that fit the bill? Tried to make it easier by splitting it into two. First part matches anything without a full stop, second part would match anything in the querystring (including your full stop) but makes sure there are no full stops before the question mark.

Comment: This is getting really close, but this one would not match (and it should match):"r:GET /?wicket:interface=:1::IActivePageBehaviorListener:15:2&wicket:ignoreIfNotActive=true&random=0.23871686266303005 HTTP/1.1" . There's the "." dot somewhere in the querystring of the url.

Comment: @rontron Updated, see if that is any better

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! Your edit didn't match at all, but I found an even more simple solution, based on your first anwser. This one did the job: "r:[A-Z]+\s([^\s\.]+)(\s|\?)"

Comment: I would strongly discourage using that regular expression, since it will fail matches that you probably want. For example, something as simple as "r:GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" will not match, since there is a `.` in the path. In other words, that regular expression rules out all file endings, not just the ones you want to rule out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
r:(?!GET [^?]+\.((?i)js|css|xml|jpg|gif|png))
```

This will produce a match whenever none of the six file endings are found in the path, though they are allowed in arguments, after a `?`. Should you want to disallow these file endings only at the end of the path, you can use this version instead:

```
r:(?!GET [^?]+\.((?i)js|css|xml|jpg|gif|png)(\?| ))
```

The difference is that the first version would not match the following line, but the second version would:

```
r:GET /img/icon_action_arrow.png.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
```